# Find the expected value for a r.v in a mixture distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Define a uniform r.v $X \sim [2, 5]$ and $c \in [2,5]$. Find the distribution of $Z= \min\{ X,c\}   $.

It seems that the distribution of $Z$ is a mixture of a continuous and a discrete r.v. To find the distribution, I did the following:

if $X \geq c$ then $Z \in [c,5]$ and if $X \leq c$ then $Z \in [2,c] \subset [2,5]$ so

$F_Z= U_{[2,c]} \frac{c-2}{3} + 1_{c \leq x} \frac{5-c}{3}$

Comment: The title asks for the expectation, the question for the distribution. Which one?

Comment: Come on, you changed the whole question from max to min *after* it was answered?

Comment: @ClementC. thanks for your help but does it affect the idea of the solution? I want the distribution to calculate the mean!

Comment: It's slightly simpler to compute the expectation directly. Whether it's the mean or the max, you only have to compute an integral which depends on the constant c.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a mixture, but you can compute this explicitly. For $z \in [2,5]$,
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{ Z \leq z\}=
\mathbb{P}\{ \max(X,c) \leq z\}=
\mathbb{P}\{ X \leq z \text{ and } c \leq z\}
= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } z<c\\
\mathbb{P}\{ X \leq z \} & \text{ if } z \geq c
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$
and since we know the distribution of $X$ (it is uniform on $[2,5]$), $\mathbb{P}\{ X \leq z \} = \frac{z-2}{3}$. Therefore, for all $z\in \mathbb{R}$
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{ Z \leq z\}=
 \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } z<c\\
\frac{z-2}{3} & \text{ if } c \leq z \leq 5\\
1 & \text{ if } z > 5
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$
(You can check that this satisfies all the conditions of a CDF: right-continuous, left-limits, and limits of 0 and 1 at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.)

Comment: I edited the question from max to min but I don't think it affects the idea of the solution! Here X is continuous and C is discrete so how $Z$ is not a mixture?

Comment: $c$ is just a constant, not a r.v. Also, a mixture is an operation on distributions, here you just have a max. Check the definition of a mixture, this doesn't fit the bill.

Comment: Why $$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{ \max(X,c) \leq z\}=
\mathbb{P}\{ X \leq z \text{ and } c \leq z\}
\end{align}$$ maybe X or c so it is
 $$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{ X \leq z \text{ or } c \leq z\}
\end{align}$$?

Comment: No: for the max of two things to be less than z, *both* must be less than z. @user0007

Answer (score 1):

If you take $\ C\ $ to be a random variable whose value is $\ c\ $ with probability $1$, and $\ Y\ $ a random variable uniformly distributed over the interval $\ [2,c]\ $ then the distribution of your $\ Z=\min(X,c)\ $ is the mixture distribution $\ \frac{c-2}{3}F_Y+\frac{5-c}{3}F_C\ $. The mean of $\ Z\ $ is therefore $\ \frac{c-2}{3}E(Y)+\frac{5-c}{3}E(C)\ $, with $\ E(C)\ $, naturally, being exactly $\  c\ $, and $\ E(Y)\ $ being the mid-point of the interval over which it is uniformly distributed.

Comment: where $F_Y$ is the cdf for a uniform over the interval $[2,c]$ and $F_c= 1_{c\leq X}$?

Comment: This is true, but seeing a max as a mixture of the conditional distribution of X and a dirac distribution on c is... Contrived. Is there literally any benefit in phrasing that simple question in this way?

Comment: Possibly not, although it  depends on what exactly you think constitutes  a "benefit".  For me, at least, it makes it easy to recognise the mean as $\ \frac{(c-2)(c+2)}{3\cdot2}+\frac{(5-c)c}{3}\ $ without having to bother about calculating any integrals.

Comment: @user0007 Yes, $\ F_Y\ $ is the uniform distribution on $\ [2,c]\ $.  I'm guessing that the $\ 1_{c\le X}\ $ in your question is a typo for $\ 1_{c\le x}\ $, which I would take to mean $\ 1_{[c,\infty)}\ $. In that case, yes also, $\ F_C=1_{[c,\infty)}\ $. The quantity $\ 1_{c\le X}\ $, however, is not a distribution function but a *random variable*, so the putative equation $\ F_C=1_{c\le X}\ $ doesn't make any sense.